# htop prompt that only 1 process running

Tags: process

htop  display the processes status as:

[image]

It prompt that 168 tasks and 667 threads,
nevertheless , only 1 is running,

It confuse me, the fact is that many processes are running

What the `1 running` is?

[image: mp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That mean that 1 process is in running state
Others are in sleep mode, stopped or defunct (zombie) mode

Linux process states:
    `Running` or `Runnable`
    `Sleeping` or `waiting`
    `Stopped`
    `Zombie`

More information:
 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state
 - https://peteris.rocks/blog/htop/#r-running-or-runnable-on-run-queue